# Moment.js - how do I build moment from date and time string?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I have given date string `MM-DD-YYYY` and time string `HH:mm A` or `H:m a`, how do I build a *moment* object?

I tried `moment('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm A')` which did not work.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try using the format (second) parameter `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`

For details see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Only this worked, formatting then finding quarter didn't

Answer (score 13):

To create a moment `object` of your desired time, do the following:

```
moment('05-17-2018 11:40 PM', 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A')
```

In this case '05-17-2018 11:40 PM' is the desired time.